# How to build minicom locally?

Tags: ubuntu, minicom

I try to build minicom locally, but there are always some issues.
This is the minicom I want to install locally:

https://salsa.debian.org/minicom-team/minicom

There is explained you have to run the ./configure file, but there is no configure file so I tried to make the installation like in the development version explained.
So first I run ./autogen.sh and the output was:

```
+ aclocal-1.16
+ [ 0 != 0 ]
+ autoheader
+ automake-1.16 -c --add-missing --force --gnu
configure.ac:17: installing './ar-lib'
configure.ac:13: installing './compile'
configure.ac:27: installing './config.guess'
configure.ac:27: installing './config.sub'
configure.ac:11: installing './install-sh'
configure.ac:11: installing './missing'
Makefile.am: installing './INSTALL'
lib/Makefile.am: installing './depcomp'
+ autoconf
```

After this, I get the configure file, so I also run it and the output was:

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a race-free mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether make supports the include directive... yes (GNU style)
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether the compiler supports GNU C... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to enable C11 features... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for stdio.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for wchar.h... yes
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
checking whether _XOPEN_SOURCE should be defined... no
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether the compiler supports GNU C... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc option to enable C11 features... (cached) none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... (cached) yes
checking dependency style of gcc... (cached) gcc3
checking for ar... ar
checking the archiver (ar) interface... ar
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for library containing strerror... none required
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for shared library run path origin... done
checking 32-bit host C ABI... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ELF binary format... yes
checking for the common suffixes of directories in the library search path... lib,lib,lib64
checking for iconv... yes
checking for working iconv... yes
./configure: line 7774: PKG_PROG_PKG_CONFIG: command not found
./configure: line 7786: syntax error near unexpected token `LOCKDEV,'
./configure: line 7786: `   PKG_CHECK_MODULES(LOCKDEV, lockdev,'
```

Here are now 3 issues. I tried anyway to run make and it didn't work, of course:

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

I have no idea how to solve it. I also tried to install some older versions but there are other problems then, for example, my packages are too new. Is there anywhere an introduction on how to install minicom locally on the machine? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: One tip to get a package that is difficult to compile to build is to look at the build definition for the upstream project, e.g. the spec file in the srpm file for rpm based system and correspondingly build description files that debian/ubuntu uses to build its dpkg files. Those should list all required (build) dependencies, so make sure you have all those installed first.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from your failed configure, on my machine...

checking for working iconv... yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for LOCKDEV... no

which says to me you need to install pkg-config and try again.